# In PHP, how can i fetch the specific children on XML?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

This the sample of xml i made

```
<Roomtypes>
        <room roomtypeid='34'>
            <name>Standard Rooms</name>
        </room >
        <room roomtypeid='36'>
            <name>Deluxe Suites </name>
        </room >
</Roomtypes>
```

my question is how can i get the specific children? for example i just only want to print standard rooms
what i want to get result is like this

**Standard Rooms**

Comment: What parser are you using?

Comment: im using php to parse it..

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." If your question is how to parse XML with PHP, the simple answer is here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php If your question is about a particular problem in code you've written, post that code and describe the problem.

Comment: How would you distinguish a *Standard Room* from any other room? You have not told in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `simplexml` to accomplish this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
```

Print all room names:

```
foreach ($xml->room as $room) {
    echo $room->name . "<br />";
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php